# USB Drive not recognized

Tags: usb, mount

I put a USB Drive into my computer and was not recognized. Can someone help me?

The computer says it was not possible to mount the USB Drive.

Comment: Can you please post the output of the command `dmesg` once you put your stick in?

Comment: post the output of `lsblk` command.

Comment: how did the computer say that it's not possible? If it was an error message then show it to us

Comment: I am assuming you mean a Flash Drive, so I've edited the question to reflect this. Please post a screenshot if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the blind (with so little info, going statistically...)

Maybe the Flash is formatted in exfat (extended FAT) format, which is not installed by default for legal (licensing) reasons.

Try from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

and try again to plug the drive in. If it doesn't work, please add more info (like the last lines of the output from the command `dmesg` or the last lines of the file `/var/log/syslog`, which should have information about the failure).

Answer (score 0):

Some folks are seeing their USB storage device show up in dmesg, lsusb, etc. (i.e. low-level success) BUT are not getting the CD or DVD auto-mounted.  My solution was as follows:

```
Checked my cable - ok.
Checked my DVD on another system - ok.
Checked my device on a Mac - ok.
Checked my USB Hub on several systems - ok.
```

Could it be the hub?  Plugged the USB device into my Linux box WITHOUT the USB hub ... success!

Moral of the story: Not all USB hubs supply enough power in each direction to qualify a device as being a mountable device.  It would be so nice in these circumstances if one got a pop-up from auto-mount or somebody saying something like "USB device blah-blah-blah does not qualify as a mountable device" - or at least, insert something that dmesg could yell about.  I don't think that it makes sense to expect an end user to diagnose voltage and current levels on a USB hub.